# Find the limit of $ n\int_{-1}^0 (x + e^x) ^ n dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, limits

I have the following limit to find:

$$\lim_{n \to \infty} n \int_{-1} ^ 0 (x + e^x)^n dx$$

Usually, when I have had to find the limit of an integral, I tried finding two boundaries for the expression inside the limit, in such a way that I could use the Squeeze Theorem, but I don't see any obvious boundaries here. Should this exercise be solved using another technique or are there boundaries which could help me?

Comment: Are you familiar with Laplace's method?  That's usually what I would use for asymptotic estimates of integrals of the form $\int_I (f(x))^n \, dx$.

Comment: @DanielSchepler: I don't know Laplace's method, but [the wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Laplace%27s_method) does not seem to be about the same kind of form of integral as this one. So can you post an answer if you have one? Anyway, no need for high-power tools; see my answer. =)

Comment: @user21820 The Wikipedia article's form would apply rewriting the integral as $\int_{-1}^0 e^{n \log(x+e^x)}\,dx$.  The article does seem to unnecessarily restrict to the case where the function has a global maximum somewhere in the interior of the interval, which isn't the case for $\log(x+e^x)$ on $[-1, 0]$.  But the same sort of argument applies and implies that the integral is asymptotic to $\int_{-\infty}^0 e^{2nx}\,dx$ based on the fact that $x+e^x = 1 + 2x + O(x^2)$ for $x$ close to 0 so $\log(x+e^x) \sim 2x$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Limit of integral without Taylor expansion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2232203/limit-of-integral-without-taylor-expansion) See also: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2617617/515527

Comment: I was thinking of an answer where a substitution $x := y/n$ gives it as the limit of $\int_{-\infty}^0 \chi_{[-n,0]}(y) (y/n + e^{y/n})^n\,dy$ where the integrand converges pointwise to $e^{2y}$.  Actually justifying the interchange of limit and integral there looks tricky, though - I'm not immediately seeing any bounding function to use in the dominated convergence theorem for example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint 1**: $\left| n·\int_a^b f(x)^n\ dx \right| \le n·(b-a)·r^n$ for any reals $a≤b$ and $f : [a,b] → \mathbb{R}$ such that $|f(x)| ≤ r$ for every $x∈[a,b]$. So you can squeeze $n·\int_{-1}^{-1/2} (x+e^x)^n\ dx ≈ 0$ as $n → ∞$.

**Hint 2**: $1+2x < x+\exp(x) < 1+2x+x^2$ for every $x∈[-1,0]$. (This should be easy for you to prove.) So you can squeeze $n·\int_{-1/2}^0 (x+e^x)^n\ dx$ between two easy integrals which have the same limit as $n → ∞$.

Comment: It all seems very clear and concise except for one thing that I can't seem to understand, perhaps you can explain it to me. In your first hint, what function did you use to approximate the integral. I understood that formula you showed, $| n \cdot \int_a^{b} f(x)^n dx | \le n \cdot ( b - a ) \cdot r^n$, but what did you use as $r$? What function did you use to conclude that the integral on the interval $[-1, -1/2]$ approaches $0$ as $n \to \infty$?

Comment: @user1502: You can pick any $r < 1$ such that $|x+e^x| ≤ r$ for every $x∈[-1,-1/2]$. I leave you to figure out one that works, since it's easy. =)